# ggplot NMDs polygon and envfit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot make both polygons and envfit on my NMDs plot. I could do separately.

1/ polygons:

```
ggplot(pts, aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,colur=as.factor(V3),fill=as.factor(V3))) +
geom_polygon(data=hulls,alpha=0.5) +
geom_point(size=0) +
geom_text(aes(label=sp$Site, color=factor(sp$Site)),size=4)
```

(See below Figure 1)

2/ envfit:

```
ggplot(pts, aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2)) + 
geom_point(size=0) + 
geom_text(aes(label=sp$Site, color=factor(sp$Site)),size=4) +
geom_segment(data=envector.df,                           
             aes(x=0,xend=NMDS1*3,y=0,yend=NMDS2*3),
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2,"cm")), 
             colour="black", inherit_aes=FALSE) + 
geom_text(data=envector.df, 
          aes(x=NMDS1*3,y=NMDS2*3,label=species), 
          size=5)+
coord_fixed()
```

(See below figure 2)

However, when I combined both codes, I got error message as below.

```
df <- pts
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$MDS1,df$MDS2),]
library(plyr)
hulls <- ddply(df,"V3", find_hull)
ggplot(pts, aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2, color=as.factor(V3), 
                fill=as.factor(V3))) +
geom_polygon(data=hulls,alpha=0.5) +
geom_point(size=0) +
geom_text(aes(label=sp$Site, color=factor(sp$Site)),size=4) +
geom_segment(data=envector.df,aes(x=0,xend=NMDS1*3,y=0,yend=NMDS2*3),
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")), colour="black",  
             inherit_aes=FALSE) + 
geom_text(data=envector.df, aes(x=NMDS1*3,y=NMDS2*3,label=species),  
          size=5) +
coord_fixed()
```

Error in is.factor(x) : object 'V3' not found

V3 is Site in my data pts or df

```
names(df)
[1] "MDS1" "MDS2" "V3"  

names(pts)
[1] "MDS1" "MDS2" "V3"
```

Appreciate if anyone could provide me some help! Thanks!
[[image]]

Comment: You need a `inherit_aes=FALSE` on your `geom_text` or it looks for `V3` in the supplied data

Comment: I used inherit_aes=FALSE on both geom_text but it still doesn't work. Anything else I did not do right?

Comment: Richard, thanks for your help! :-D It works now when I used inherit.aes instead of inherit_aes. Cheers!